# How to disable past dates in MaterialDatePicker?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker, material-components-android, material-components

```
 //Material Date Picker
private val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
private val constraintsBuilder = CalendarConstraints.Builder().setStart(calendar.timeInMillis)
private val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
private val picker = builder
    .setSelection(calendar.timeInMillis)
    .setInputMode(MaterialDatePicker.INPUT_MODE_CALENDAR)
    .setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build())
    .build()
```

I am using above code to open calendar setSelection method select current date and setStart only works for current month So i am unable to select previous month dates but **i can still select past dates of current month.**

If any can help me out. Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can build your own `DateValidator` or you can just use the **`DateValidatorPointForward`** provided by the library.

Something like:

```
//Returns a DateValidator which enables days from {@code point}, in 
//UTC milliseconds, forward
CalendarConstraints.DateValidator dateValidator = DateValidatorPointForward.from(yourDate);
constraintsBuilder.setValidator(dateValidator);
```

[image]

Comment: I did this but for me it's working fine but i am unable to select current date from your code. it is blocking to select current date also.

Comment: 1.One more thing i wanted to ask suppose i selected next month of date then i am opening calendar than that date is selected but calendar doesn't scroll to that month. Any idea how to do it ?

2. If i am changing **builder** instance from **datepicker()** to **daterangepicker()** it is not taking the default theme and **not opening as dailog it is opening as full screen**.

Comment: @DeepakRajput Your question is not so clear. The DateValidator is the way to able/unable the dates. Which value are you using it the from method? Which version of the library are you using and which theme are you using in the app?

Comment: What i am saying is your date validator is working but it is not allowing me to select current date. It is allowing me to select from the day after the current date. So suppose it's 24 today then i can't select 24 i can select from 25 only.

Comment: @DeepakRajput It depends by the value that you are using in the `from` method (it is in UTC milliseconds). If you need to validate all dates>= now just use the `dateValidator = DateValidatorPointForward.now();`

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your own [`DateValidator`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/CalendarConstraints.java#L47) for this. A date being enabled/disabled depends on whether `DateValidator.isValid()` returns true or false

```
@Parcelize
class FutureDateValidator : CalendarConstraints.DateValidator {
    override fun isValid(date: Long): Boolean {
        return date > System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
}
```

And then use this validator as:

```
CalendarConstraints.Builder()
    .setValidator(FutureDateValidator())
    .build()
```

Comment: Same thing happening with your code unable to select current date.